# Setup chrome proxy settings form extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I develop a chrome extension for proxy servers.
I get servers (and it authorization data) list through API, after I set IP and PORT to chrome settings:

```
connect: function(proxyData, callback) {

    this.setListener(proxyData);
    chrome.proxy.settings.set(
        {
            value: {
                mode: "fixed_servers",
                rules: {
                    singleProxy: {
                        scheme: "http",
                        host: proxyData.ip,
                        port: parseInt(proxyData.port)
                    },
                }
            },
            scope: 'regular'
        },
        function() {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(proxyData);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

After that I add autorization listener:

```
setListener: function(proxyData) {
    let username = proxyData.username,
        password = proxyData.password;
    this.proxyAuthFunction = function(details, callbackFn) {
        console.log(username, password, 'Init proxy auth function');
        callbackFn({authCredentials: { username: username, password: password}});
    };
    if (chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.hasListener(this.proxyAuthFunction)) {
        chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.removeListener(this.proxyAuthFunction);
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        this.proxyAuthFunction,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["asyncBlocking"]
    );
}
```

It doesn't work, and browser asks a base authorization anyway.

But hardcode works good and browser don't ask base authorization:

```
setListener: function(proxyData) {
    let username = 'qwerty',
        password = 'qwerty';
    this.proxyAuthFunction = function(details, callbackFn) {
        console.log(username, password, 'Init proxy auth function');
        callbackFn({authCredentials: { username: username, password: password}});
    };
    if (chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.hasListener(this.proxyAuthFunction)) {
        chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.removeListener(this.proxyAuthFunction);
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        this.proxyAuthFunction,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["asyncBlocking"]
    );
}
```

Has anyone encountered with a similar problem?